# Does Mac OS X use Linux?

Tags: linux, macos

The title says it all. At my job I've been asked to install a Ubuntu Linux system on a Virtualbox among other things so I can ssh into a development environment. This got me wondering about Operating Systems. I understand that Apple's is Mac OS X, but I just want to know if Mac OS X uses Linux or not. In August, I'm thinking of signing up for a Linux class on Edx.org so I can get better with the command line. I want to know if it will be a waste of time or not.

I've already looked up the history of Linux, Looked it up on Wikipedia, and googled it but surprisingly I didn't find an answer to this question. So once again, does Mac use Linux?

Comment: This graph shows the family pretty nicely: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Unix_history-simple.png

Comment: Unix is not Linux. Linux is not Unix.

Comment: Thanks! This was a good graph and very helpful. This cleared it up nicely.

Comment: OSX, Unix, and GNU/Linux *do* have a lot in common WRT the command line, however.

Comment: Historical trivia - For the Motorola based Mac's, Apple did have a version of unix called [A/UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/UX). For the "classic" Motorola based Mac OS from 1 to 6 or 7 (before the switch to Power PC, and later X86), Apple kept promising but never implemented a preemptive operating system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mac OSX is built on top of BSD.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X

Linux classes, in my opinion, are just fine and would enable you to be comfortable with the command line. The caveat is that there are differences such as the output or availability or options of commands. Instance is "ps". The system libraries, the folder structure are also different. Also note if you ever work on a *NIX server machine, invariably that would be linux. Note, there are no OSX servers anymore.

Comment: "Invariably"? If I was setting up an enterprise, I'd be strongly tempted to use OpenBSD for my servers.

Comment: https://w3techs.com/technologies/comparison/os-bsd,os-linux

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X is based on BSD. BSD is similar to Linux but it is **not** Linux. However a big number of commands is identical.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Mac OS X is based on [Darwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29), which is a descendant of Unix

It depends on the course, a shell scripting/bash course might be helpful since mostly the same commands are used, with some exceptions (some commands which are only specific to Mac OS X)

Answer (score 0):

OSX uses Darwin, which is an OpenBSD variant. It is "UNIX-Like"

That means that while many aspects will be similar to linux, **not EVERYTHING** is the same.

For instance, the file system resembles linux, but has some differences such as the frameworks directories, /Applications, /Library, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I started with Linux quite some time ago, at a point it gives you a pretty insight into how other systems work in general. But when you want to learn it just for an ssh from the terminal, you are effectively wasting your time. There is a command line on every operating system out there, unless it was prohibited from use by the administrator from the admin account. They need to kill the process completely, just to keep you away from it. On another hand, if you learn Linux, you would be able to adapt to the server environment because in the server rooms everything runs from the terminal. You can rarely find any enterprise architecture running on a GUI environment, and it gives you plenty of space for creativity because most of the applicants have never seen a server terminal equipment to begin with. Each terminal has their own language, so if you are learning OS X terminal it has a different set of terms than Windows terminal, Ubuntu terminal and other server equipment. In each one of them "learning" process is set from do-fail-repeat-fail-succeed-destroy-repeat. There is no single efficient way of doing that all.